# postgresql failing to create function with text input parameter

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql 13.13. Any derivative of the following function is successfully created but my parameter is missing from the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_user_and_related_data(p_username TEXT)
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    v_uid INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Get UID based on the provided username
    SELECT uid INTO v_uid FROM users WHERE username = p_username;

    -- Delete records from user_sessions where uid matches
    DELETE FROM user_sessions WHERE uid = v_uid;
    
    ---more delete queries...

    -- Delete record from users where username matches
    DELETE FROM users WHERE username = p_username;
END;
$$;
```

I have tried defining the parameter as a varchar, prepending the variable with "IN" nada.  If I view the function the parameter is missing if I try to call the function I get:

> delete_user_and_related_data(unknown) is not a procedure

Here is what the object looks like after defining:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "public"."delete_user_and_related_data"() RETURNS void LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$

DECLARE
    v_uid INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Get UID based on the provided username
    SELECT uid INTO v_uid FROM users WHERE username = p_username;

    -- Delete records from user_sessions where uid matches
    DELETE FROM user_sessions WHERE uid = v_uid;

    -- Delete records from zofolio_user_dream_coins where uid matches
    DELETE FROM zofolio_user_dream_coins WHERE uid = v_uid;

    -- Delete records from zofolio_user_trades where uid matches
    DELETE FROM zofolio_user_trades WHERE uid = v_uid;

    -- Delete record from users where username matches
    DELETE FROM users WHERE username = p_username;
END;

$$
```

Using DBGrip, I wouldn't think that would matter.  I have also tried to create a procedure with the same info and have the same problem.

Comment: 1) In `psql` `\df delete_user_and_related_data` returns `Schema |             Name             | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+------
 public | delete_user_and_related_data | void             | p_username text     | func
` 2) You `CALL` a `procedure` you `SELECT` a `function` e.g. `select delete_user_and_related_data('some_name');` 3) Postgres allows overloading functions, my guess is you have more then one form of `delete_user_and_related_data`

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue over here, works fine. But, when using a foreign key, you wouldn't need this code anyway.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  only one function with that name: select routine_name from information_schema.routines where routine_type = 'FUNCTION' AND routine_schema = 'public';
         routine_name         
------------------------------
 delete_user_and_related_data
(1 row)

Comment: I figured out how to get it to work.  I have a database named SomeDB and was trying to create and execute the function using a user named SomeDB.  I deleted the function and then logged in using the postgres user, did everything exactly the same and now it works.  So I guess the SomeDB user didn't have permission?  But why was it allowing me to create the function in the first place?  The SomeDB has "Create DB" permissions, I really don't understand.

Comment: 1) Your information_schema query was limited to `routine_type = 'FUNCTION'`, so you could very well have missed `procedure`s you created with the same name. 2) In `psql` do \du SomeDB and see what attributes that user has. 3) Any user has the rights of the `PUBLIC` role granted to them per [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) and per [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html): *PostgreSQL grants privileges on some types of objects to PUBLIC by default when the objects are created. ...  EXECUTE privilege for functions and procedures; ...*

Comment: You need to spend time reading the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

*Q: if I try to call the function I get:
delete_user_and_related_data(unknown) is not a procedure*

That happens when using `CALL` to call a function, instead of `SELECT`.

`SELECT` should be used to call functions (declared with `CREATE FUNCTION`), even those that return `void`, whereas `CALL` is for procedures (declared with `CREATE PROCEDURE`).

*Q: If I view the function the parameter is missing*

If you first have created the function without an argument, and then a function with same name but with an argument, you get **two different functions**. This is known as [Function Overloading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html). You want to drop the function without argument if you don't need it:

```
DROP FUNCTION delete_user_and_related_data();
```

If you wanted to drop the other function, you could write

```
DROP FUNCTION delete_user_and_related_data(text);
```

Dropping the version you don't need should clear the confusion leading to looking at the wrong one with the client-side SQL tool you're using.